# How do you search by DN in LDAP?

Tags: perl, active-directory, ldap

I'm pulling information about a user from LDAP. This includes directReports, which is in the full `CN=cnBlah, OU=ouBlah, DC=dcBlah` form. I'm trying to do another lookup to find info about the reportee.

So far the only way I've been able to actually find said user is to break out the `CN=` and set the remainder of the string as the base.

Is this the proper way of doing it? Or is there a way to search for an entry given the full DN?

Answer (score 13):

Use the DN as the base object in the search and set the scope of the search to `base`.

Comment: I found (in another post by Terry) that the magic combination seems to be: 1) set search base to the DN you are looking up.  2) set your search filter to "(&)".

Comment: This seems so obvious in hindsight, but was not obvious and an Internet search leads here! I searched `ldapsearch dn`.

Answer (score 3):

Closing the loop on this question, courtesy of https://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200503/msg00520.html

> When you know the DN of an entry, there is no need to "search" for it all, just retrieve the entry directly:
> ldapsearch -x -LLL -b "uid=droy,ou=people,dc=eclipse,dc=org"

So that answers the "how do you use ldapsearch to lookup() an item rather than search for it"

Comment: `-x` is unrelated; this changes how you authenticate to the LDAP server. `-LLL` changes the output format (removes some of the extraneous info and comments). And this command as a whole retrieves all entries including *and under* the entry in question.

Answer (score 2):

Calling [`ldapsearch` with the `-f` option](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/ldap-utils/ldapsearch.1.en.html#f) would do pretty much what you want.

Save your first search results to a file, with only the **value** of the `cn` attribute. For example, your file would look like this :

**users.txt:**

```
user1
user2
cnBlah
john
jim
user883
```

Then call ldapsearch with a base that is high enough to encompass all users. This could be `-b dc=users,dc=example,dc=com`.

So if you saved your user list to a file named `users.txt`, your ldapsearch command line would look like this :

```
#I removed the hostname, port and authentification for clarity
ldapsearch -b "dc=users,dc=example,dc=com" -s sub "cn=%s" -f users.txt -LLL
```

Long lines will wrap at ~76 characters. Nothing that a pipe through `perl -p00e 's/\r?\n //g'` can't fix. (Or just add option [`-o ldif-wrap=no`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/ldap-utils/ldapsearch.1.en.html#o) to your ldapsearch commandline.)